# Delegated SSO redirection to custom client page after logout

Tags: single-sign-on, delegate

We have implemented a delegated SSO with sfdc using Java webservices (Connected to LDAP directory).After the logout from sfdc the client wants the redirection to happen to their server pages rather than sfdc standard login page. Is it doable? If possible please help me with some documentation link for same.

Please note I have not use federated SSO or configured SAML. It is a simple delegated SSO service.

Comment: Can someone please answer this question? I'm interested in the same but for Marketing Cloud. @lukas lenow any idea?